# Make table using object

Tags: javascript, object, url, dom, html-table

I'm making a table but using only Javascript. I did the table already and it shows right on console, but I can't make it visible on the page. I tried `appendChild()` and `insertBefore()` and it doesn't work, and also can't make the URL clickable.

Here is my code:

```
var companies = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Google',
        link: 'http://google.com/'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Microsoft',
        link: 'http://microsoft.com/'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Apple',
        link: 'http://apple.com'
    }
];



var tbl = document.createElement('table');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

var tr_head = document.createElement("tr");

var th_id = document.createElement("th");
var th_name = document.createElement("th");
var th_link = document.createElement("th");

th_id.textContent = "Id";
th_name.textContent = "Name";
th_link.textContent = "link";


tr_head.appendChild(th_id);
tr_head.appendChild(th_name);
tr_head.appendChild(th_link);

thead.appendChild(tr_head);

for(var i = 0;  i < companies.length; i++) {
    var tr_body = document.createElement("tr");

    var td_id = document.createElement("td");
    var td_name = document.createElement("td");
    var td_link = document.createElement("td");

    // var id = companies[i].id;
    // var name = companies[i].name;
    // var link = companies[i].link;

    td_id.textContent = companies[i].id;
    td_name.textContent = companies[i].name;
    td_link.textContent = companies[i].link;

    tr_body.appendChild(td_id);
    tr_body.appendChild(td_name);
    tr_body.appendChild(td_link);

    tbody.appendChild(tr_body);
}

tbl.appendChild(thead);
tbl.appendChild(tbody);

console.log(tbl);

// input.appendChild(tbl);
```

Comment: Have you verified using developer tools that the element has been added to the DOM? Also, it looks like you are attempting to write the table to an `input` element, that won't work. You should change the input to a `div`, `section`, `body`, etc. tag and call `appendChild` on that

Answer (score 0):

Do you write the output to the document? Else it will just remain in the script.

Like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but it's a way...

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");

var rows = "";

for(var i = 0;  i < companies.length; i++) {
  rows += "<tr><td>"+companies[i].id+"</td>"
        + "<td><a href='"+companies[i].link+"'>"+companies[i].name+"</a></td></tr>"
}

var table = "<table>"+rows+"</table>";

input.innerHTML = table;
```

Comment: i know that way too, but I'm trying to do the same thing but not using html at all, type all codes in javascript